# Express + Nunjucks - Is there a template tag similar to Django's {% url "..." %}

Tags: express, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks as the template engine for an Express web app.  I come from building websites from Django, and Django's templates come with the very useful `{% url "..." %}` tag which allows you to change your URL's in the URL controller and have all associated URL's automatically updated.

Does such a feature exist for Express + Nunjucks?  In the Nunjucks docs I see `urlencode` and `urlize` but these don't perform the function I'm looking for.